# What is the latest version of Cygwin's Setup that will run in Windows 7?

Tags: installation, windows-7, cygwin

.. And how can I get that not-latest version?

Greetings, gurus and other experts.

Reactionary that I am, I'm still using a Windows-7 PC for most of my work.  My cygwin setup program is `setup-x86_64` on release 2.919.  Today it popped up with the message that **release 2.230 is available** so I downloaded it like a good little nerd. When I ran 2.230 I got the popup:

[**Cygwin is not supported on this Windows version**]

Bummer!  Not a big bummer, like tasting your first beer, but a bummer nevertheless. :-)

This invites two questions:

- What *is* the latest release of the Cygwin setup-x86_64 that will run under Windows 7?
- How do I tell the [Cygwin download page](https://cygwin.com/install.html) that I want a specific release of the Setup, not necessarily the latest release?  That page does not seem to display an  option for a less-than-latest download.  And it does not seem to be listed among the available packages (which makes sense.)

Not the highest priority, since the 2.19 seem to be adequate for my modest Cygwin needs, but I still have the typical fixation on getting the latest available releases.

Ideas, anyone?  Much thanks!

-- JS

PS: What I've tried:

- Eyeball-scanned the Cygwin install page for an option to install a specific release of setup-86_64
- Looked for Setup in the list of packages

Comment: Addendum: There is indeed a section of the install page that asks "How can I install the last Cygwin version for an old, unsupported Windows?" However, the URL provided in the chart for Windows-7 also omits the setup program itself.  Grumble.

Answer (score 0):

Previous versions of Cygwin Setup are available at

https://www.cygwin.com/setup/

In the future if you need to install old version of any program you can use

http://www.crouchingtigerhiddenfruitbat.org/Cygwin/timemachine.html

Comment: Thanks matzeri.

However, that still leaves me to guess (binary search?) which release, between 2.919 and 2.930, is the latest supported under Windows-7

Apologies for the repeated typos about 2.230 when the version I was discussing was 2.930.

Comment: https://cygwin.com/pipermail/cygwin-announce/2024-February/011525.html